# Remove space between span and text element

Tags: css, text, html

I'm trying to make a header's background color look like a rectangular speech bubble by adding a text element ◥. Below you can see the spanned text for the background shape and the style for ◥. But this creates a blank space between the bottom of the border and the ◥, and I would like the two to line up in order to look like a speech bubble.

Image of fail in action.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0qnP.png

```
{block:Link}      
    <h1><span class="Headers"><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name} ☞</a></span>
        <div class="triangle">◥</div>
    </h1>
{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}    
{/block:Link}


.triangle{
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #123033;
}
span.Headers{
    display: block;
    background-color: #123033;
    padding: 8px
}
```

I tried the trick with adding a parent group in which the font size is 0, and that didn't work. Nor did setting the margin on the header to 0. Putting the ◥ div on the same line hasn't done anything either. I spent about an hour looking through other questions to see what I could do, and I couldn't find a solution, but I am nub so forgive me if I missed something obvious.

Comment: You mean, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/QzajU/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unreliable to use text to create the effect. Different devices will render it differently, which is not what you want.

In your case, it would be best to use an image with the same colour, placing it in a `<div/>` below the heading, ensuring that they touch each other. Then, add some padding on the left, as you did with the `.triangle` style.

I have created an image for you to use: [Grab it here](http://ge.tt/4vM16SN/v/0?c)

All in all, your markup would look like this:

HTML:

```
{block:Link}   
    <div class="header">
        <h1><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name} ☞</a></h1>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>  
{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}    
{/block:Link}
```

CSS:

```
div.header > h1 {
    background-color: #123033;
    padding: 8px
}

div.header > div.triangle {
    background: url('Arrow.png') top left no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px
}
```

Do let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Michael, you're the man! With this I was able to get that triangle right under the box, thank you. One last question for you: when I used padding-left the triangle didn't actually show up at all (perhaps hidden in the box), I changed it to padding-top and it does appear, but I can't get both to work so my triangle is stuck on the very left side of the h1 box. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try giving the triangle block a height of 50px in CSS, and leave out any upper padding. If there is any overlapping going on, ensure that both the H1 and the triangle block are set to `display: block`. I tried editing my answer yesterday, but now see that it failed.

Comment: I have now edited my answer to reflect. And are you sure it is finding the `Arrow.png` image?

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by resizing the image and doing some padding, but your way totally works too. Thanks a million dude, you have helped my comprehension of HTML and CSS. Check me out at tumblr.com/naritachi... I'll have posts soon :D

VC

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use generated content (which, I suppose, depends on your site's users), then I'd suggest (with the slightly amended HTML for demo purposes):

```
<h1><span class="Headers"><a href="#something">a name</a></span></h1>​
```

The following CSS:

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffa;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

h1::after {
    content: '';
    border: 1em solid #ffa;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 2em;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QzajU/1/).

In terms of compatibility [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) suggests that generated content is supported in IE from version 8 onwards.

References:

- [CSS generated content compatibility, from caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).